# Linux mint 17.3 doesn't shut down

Tags: linux-mint, shutdown, reboot

Just installed Linux Mint 17.3 with KDE on HP probook 6470B.  Installation went well, the system said it was restarting - DVD was ejected and system seemed to shut down but it didn't. I tried Ctrl+Alt+Del but got message from `root@mint` that it was starting emergency keypress handling, then stopping emergency keypress handling, then starting store sound card state, and lastly stopping store sound card state.

I can type on the screen but there's no terminal. How do I recover from this state?

Comment: Have you tried powering it down? It'll probably sort itself out when it next boots up.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason Linux Mint sometimes has problems shutting down after boot from CD. (what is even weirder, for me it was happening for apparently 2 different reasons with different things displayed on screen) When it reaches that stage simply click the power button - it's not using the hard drive at this point and can't corrupt any data.